# how to define a connection string using an app.config file in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string, app-config

Currently i manually define my connection string in my C# code:

```
string ConnectionString = "Data Source=C;Initial Catalog=tickets;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
Conn.Open();
```

In my project i have an app.config file and i can see that it has a connection string.
It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ticketNotification.Properties.Settings.ticketsConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=C;Initial Catalog=tickets;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

How can i define the connection string based on the app.config file in the same folder as my application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get connection strings from the app.config file you use the class ConfigurationManager located in the System.Configuration namespace.

To get the connection string by name and create a connection based on it, you can use the following code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
      ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
         "ticketNotification.Properties.Settings.ticketsConnectionString"]
             .ConnectionString);
```

You can read more about this here (MSDN Documentation):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx

Ensure your project holds a reference to System.Configuration, otherwise ConfigurationManager
will not be available in the System.Configuration namespace.

Regards.

Comment: In .net 4.5 that doesnt exist

Comment: Have you opened my link to MSDN, it's on .NET 4.5 and clearly illustrates examples using it. Are you saying that MSDN is incorrect?!

Comment: As you have helped me in the comments. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Glade to help a fellow!

Answer (score 10):

Modify your application with this

App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
         <add name="ticketNotification.Properties.Settings.ticketsConnectionString"
              connectionString="Data Source=C;Initial Catalog=tickets;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
  </configuration>
```

and here is your code behind file. You need to use `System.Configuration` Namespace. `System.Configuration` namespace contains `ConfigurationManager` class which is used to get connection string from `app.config/web.config` files.

As this is a windows application you have `App.config` file where you have defined your connection string. To get that connectionstring defined in the configuration file you need to use below line of codes inside your required eventhandler

Add this namespace to your code behind (ex: `Form1.cs`) file

```
using System.Configuration;
```

And here inside the eventhandler add/modify these codes

```
  string myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ticketNotification.Properties.Settings.ticketsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

  using(SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
  {
     Conn.Open();
     //Define the SQL query need to be executed as a string

    //Create your command object

    //Create Dataset,Dataadapter if required

    //add parameters to your command object - if required

   //Execute your command

   //Display success message
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly add a reference to System.Configuration by right-clicking References and selecting Add reference.  Then use

```
Using System.Configuration

// within the class here

ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ticketNotification.Properties.Settings.ticketsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Obviously you will need to put in the name of your connection string in the brackets.

Comment: I am using .net 4.5 and configurationManager doesnt exist!

Comment: Adding Using System.Configuration does not work

Comment: According to this it does http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.  You need to add the reference then a Using System.Configuration call at the top.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Add reference to System.configuration assembly

Comment: The properties you have written dont exist. Wait ill show you

Comment: The connection is called "ticketsConnectionString" but how does it know to read that particular app.config file in the directory?????

Comment: Use the full connection string - please see edit.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton according to you the connection is called "ticketNotification.Properties.Settings.ticketsConnectionString". Also note that, app.config is a configuration file of the application, when you use ConfigurationManager it will read the configuration of the application locate in that file, it's convention.

Comment: `The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context `

Comment: AND i have added `using System.Configuration`

Comment: @PriceCheaperton But it is working or not?! Maybe there is other problems in your project preventing it to work.

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Ok, easy, do you know how to add references to your projects?

Comment: Try right-clickuing the ConfigurationManager item and see if there is a "resolve" option.  IF so, select it.

Comment: I know how to add references

Comment: @PriceCheaperton can you check that you have a reference called System.Configuration in your project? I'm not talking about the "using" at the top of the file.

Comment: I think i am missing a system reference from the project!

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Yes, that it. One thing is add an import "using" to a reference at the top of the file. The other is add a reference to the project file itself.

Comment: Nice! It's kind of counter intuitive because you can use classes that exist inside the System.Configuration leading you to assume everything is ok, but if you do not import the System.Configuration there are some classes that are not available like System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to System.Configuration to your project. You will then be able to add the `using System.Configuration` statement and get the connection string by name using:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[<name>].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: The connection is called "ticketsConnectionString" is that what i put for the name? with the angled brakets?

Comment: Yes. It is a string so enclose it in quotations. Remove the angled brackets. Ex: "connectionStringName"

Comment: Probably you have .Net 4.5 Client Profile in Project properties and that' why, you are not able to add the reference to System.configuration. If so, please change the Project Properties settings to point to .Net 4.5 ("Client" word shouldn't be there). You can go to Project Settings --> Application tab --> look for Target Framework ( it should be set to .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: @James: I believe that got sorted already. The reference needed to be made.