# How to configure a connection to a database of my C# application on another machine

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework

I developed a winForm application with C # using entity framework on visual studio 2019 with a MySQL database, everything works on my machine. BUT when I install it on another machine I do not find how to configure it so that it connects to the database that is on another machine on a local network ... basically, I want to configure `(" Database =; Data Source =; User Id =; Password = ")`

need help, please.

Comment: you should create connectionstring in config file like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871776/how-to-define-a-connection-string-using-an-app-config-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: Set `Data Source = "OtherPCIP"`

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to these solutions, I found the connection information to the database in the app.config file, I just have to add a window to include a custom modification of this file.